# How to save save user's facebook profile picture to my domain/website data using php

Tags: php, facebook, curl, profile, image

i want to save the user's profile picture of facebook to my disk, it is more like scrapping user's profile picture db when they registered first.'

for example here is the url.

https://graph.facebook.com/{id}/picture

i want to save it under a specific directory. 
also, if there is not picture, i want to download the default placeholder as well, which is GIF. the above url is actually having a placeholder only.

i am beginner in php, please explain me in detail.

Comment: I'm no expert on Facebook's copyright policy, but it might be worth checking if this is allowed within the T&Cs (and/or whether you also need to ask the user).

Comment: It appears that Facebook lets you do what you want with publicly available information such as information from the user_profile: In addition, when you download or use such third-party services, they can access your Public Profile, which includes your username or user ID, your age range and country/language, your list of friends, as well as any information that you share with them. Information collected by these apps, websites or integrated services is subject to their own terms and policies. https://www.facebook.com/policy.php from the section on 'How is this information shared?'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<?php
$image = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/100003027438870/picture'); // sets $image to the contents of the url
file_put_contents('/path/image.gif', $image); // places the contents in the file /path/image.gif
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i never thought it is this easy. i was trying to use curl based on  suggestions in various forums, but that actually never worked, thanks. i believe loading  facebook profile image is legal once user gives permission.

Comment: @Tylio, i did it. thanks. i did not know community standard since am new to this :)

Comment: @Tylio it used to work well untill now, however it has started failing and says cannot open stream...

Comment: @asm234 You need to make sure that the path to the image exists. For example if you are saving to `/pathname/image.gif`, make sure that the `/pathname` exists.

Comment: @Tylio yes path exists and as i said earlier it used to work fine.. path and everything is still same... but has started failing suddently.. and say that says cannot open stream it fails on $image = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/id/picture');

Comment: @Tylio it has been resolved and the earlier solution remains true...it had started failing all of a sudden in between... i guess some fb API issue... however i added exception catches to avoid any issues thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

function curl_redir_exec($ch)
    {
        static $curl_loops = 0;
        static $curl_max_loops = 20;
        if ($curl_loops++ >= $curl_max_loops)
        {
            $curl_loops = 0;
            return FALSE;
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        @list($header, $data) = @explode("\n\n", $data, 2);
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($http_code == 301 || $http_code == 302)
        {
            $matches = array();
            preg_match('/Location:(.*?)\n/', $header, $matches);
            $url = @parse_url(trim(array_pop($matches)));
            if (!$url)
            {
                //couldn't process the url to redirect to
                $curl_loops = 0;
                return $data;
            }
            $last_url = parse_url(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL));
            if (!$url['scheme'])
                $url['scheme'] = $last_url['scheme'];
            if (!$url['host'])
                $url['host'] = $last_url['host'];
            if (!$url['path'])
                $url['path'] = $last_url['path'];
            $new_url = $url['scheme'] . '://' . $url['host'] . $url['path'] . (@$url['query']?'?'.$url['query']:'');
            return $new_url;
        } else {
            $curl_loops=0;
            return $data;
        }
    }

    function get_right_url($url) {
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        return curl_redir_exec($curl);
    }

    $url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' . $fbid . '/picture?type=large';

    $file_handler = fopen('img/avatar/'.$fbid.'.jpg', 'w');
    $curl = curl_init(get_right_url($url));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file_handler);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    fclose($file_handler);
```